# How to structure solution files and folders to fit best with MVP design-pattern?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, mvp

Can you advice on structering the solution projects, files, fodlers in a way that it matches with the MVP design pattern in order to represent the pattern idea?

I mean how would you put your presenters, data acces layer, views etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution architectures are generally pretty independent of which UI architecture you're using, although you might have some additional separation *if* you plan to have multiple UI applications (most projects don't).

I tend to start out with a template similar to this:

- `Acme.Sales` or `Acme.Sales.Core` - internal domain/business logic
- `Acme.Sales.Entities` - data entities used for persistence layers. Entities have similar class structure to the core (domain) model, but tend to have thinner logic, additional properties like `Id`, two-way relationships (as opposed to the one-way relationships in the domain model), and `virtual` members for the ORM to be able to override. This assembly will also normally include *abstract* repositories for CRUD operations on entities.
- `Acme.Sales.Entities.Impl` where `Impl` is something like `LinqToSql` or `NHibernate` - this namespace defines one possible implementation for actually persisting the `Entities`. *Concrete* implementations of the abstract repositories go here.
- `Acme.Sales.UI` contains common classes relating to *any* user interface - might be an MVP GUI or even a CLI. As with `Entities`, these are *similar* to the `Core` classes but tend to have presentation-specific logic and attributes, such as validation and formatting (which most often today is done through `DataAnnotations`).  Note that the core library should *also* validate, but UI validation tends to be more about formatting and sanitization of inputs than business rules. It's tempting to mimic the domain's class structure here, but you'll have an easier time overall if you stick to flat, DTO-style classes for your UI model.
- `Acme.Sales.UI.Services` contains abstract or concrete "service" types that are meant to interact with both the UI *and* the domain/persistence layers. Thus this project takes dependencies on `Acme.Sales` (domain), `Acme.Sales.Entities` (abstract repositories), as well as `Acme.Sales.UI`, and handles all of the mapping activities between those different layers.
- `Acme.Sales.UI.Impl` where `Impl` here is something like `Mvp`, `Mvc`,`Mvvm`, and so on. You can drop the `UI` from this namespace if you want, as the implementation implies what it is. This generally takes a dependency on the `UI` project but adds those things specific to a particular UI model; controllers, presenters, view-models, etc. This is your actual "application". It's also where you normally choose an IoC container (AutoFac, Ninject, Spring.NET, Castle, Unity) and wire up all the specific implementations to the abstract types.
- Within your application project you'd want to separate logical concepts into different sub-namespaces/folders. For example put your presenters in `Presenters` and views in `Views` - pretty straightforward - and create subdirectories in each of those if you start getting a really huge number of screens (e.g. `Views.Billing` and `Views.Shipping`). It's also OK to create top-level `Area` directories/namespaces here and put separate `Presenters`, `Views`, etc. in each one of those areas - this is the approach currently taken in ASP.NET MVC.

You *don't* need to separate `Presenters` and `Views` into different projects. Rest assured that the views which you tailor-made for MVP will be utterly useless for MVC or MVVM, and vice versa. The only part of a model-driven app that really stands a chance of being reused is the model itself.

Note that this is just a very basic architecture for an app with a single database and relatively simple domain logic. It doesn't include any higher-level back-end constructs like app integration (e.g. web services), eventing (pub/sub), batch processing, CQS, ad-hoc reporting, and so on and so forth. These tend to be pretty common in larger-scale business apps but if you're just starting out on a new social bookmarking app then you don't need any of that complexity.

Also note: This is all assuming you're planning at least a medium-size project - let's say one that you and/or your team will be working on for 6 months or more. If you plan to bang it all out in 1 month or less then please, don't waste your time on solution architectures at all. It's perfectly OK to just jam it all into one project and reuse the same classes for domain, entities, *and* UI - **as long as** the project is small enough to be easily understood and maintained. Carefully monitor the complexity and maintenance overhead and consider refactoring into the above structure over a longer period of time if the project starts turning into a ball of mud.

Comment: If view and presenter is not separated into two different projects, then what if I need to change the view? In your case I will need to rewrite the entire presenter model again in another project. Instead you should have presenter in one project along with `IView`, and real view in another. Now its just a matter of having `mobile.view`, `web.view` etc etc so that you have different views, but a single presenter maintaining them..

Comment: @nawfal: I already addressed that in the last bullet point. I don't think I'd recommend actually putting them in separate assemblies - neither of them are really reusable - but whether you use namespaces or actual projects, you're still namespacing first by implementation (`Mvp`) and then by type (`Views` or `Presenters`). FWIW, I've more recently taken a liking to not using the type as a category at all and namespacing by feature or functional area; views and presenters/viewmodels/controllers are so interdependent that trying to separate them often just adds unnecessary overhead.

Comment: They are reusable. If they aren't, why have all the pain in even thinking about presenter/controller? Why not just write all the UI logic in View? The presenter has absolutely nothing to do with type of View, instead it only has an interface `IView` that defines a set of methods/events that presenter should act on. You can have custom implementation of `IView` in different `Views`. After all that's the main point of MVP isn't it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Now all this is possible only if we separate View and Presenter into two projects. Otherwise it might be possible by referencing one View from another which is pure bloat

Comment: @nawfal: I'm sorry, but no; "bloat" is having 30 projects in a solution when you only need 10, and that gets very painful with regard to build times as the SLOC grows. There are plenty of tools like NDepend which can identify circular namespace dependencies and report them in the build metrics from your CI process (or just ad-hoc, if you're not on a big team). This is exactly what namespaces are *meant* for - separating features or layers within a *single* project.

Comment: You can control it. You can control it by not spreading libraries unnecessarily into separate projects, but have it all under single project, may be where your Domain lies. In other words have all libraries classes that will be reused in one project. Inside the project you can always sub-classify with namespaces or whatever. True I have seen projects being spawned without any reason often, but that has to be controlled.

Comment: In such a case you will end up with 30 projects only if you have 25 different views(a web application, an android app, a desktop one, a native facebook app etc etc upto 30, just saying) considering 5 projects are reserved for the "bloat" (say model, DAL, persistence, presenter, whatever). That's pretty an efficient number for 30 different apps you know. That's good business in fact :) Lets rethink if you will ever have 30 different "such" projects. But for two or three gui applications the benefit of having a separate presenter is huge. Your approach wont guarantee that.

Comment: Further more no MVP/MVVM/MVC solution is going to create 30 projects that you could have otherwise limited to 10 projects. Design patterns will at best form 5 or 6 extra projects. At best.. The question is relevant, what advantage are you even gaining by having presenter along with view but in different namespaces? Nothing but additional complexity. You have less brain wracking to do if you can write ui logic in view itself. If you're bringing View and Presenter in one project, what's even the point of MVP to talk about?

Comment: True in real life scenarios one view may be a bit different from another and hence a web.presenter may not fit for desktop.presenter. Similarly you would want db projects 1 and 2. In such cases you will want to have additional projects, but thats still wont be as big a bloat as you're saying, besides that, the benefit is huge (imo)

Comment: @nawfal: You don't write (much) UI code in the view because it's against the architecture, and makes maintenance more difficult. If you significantly change your presenter, *all* the views still have to be updated, so having them all in separate projects gains you nothing in terms of maintainability, just a lot in terms of compiler and source control overhead. You're a expressing an opinion based on absolutely zero facts, and I'd appreciate if you refrained from continuing to do so on my answer; if you think you've got a better system, post it as your own answer.

Comment: //You don't write (much) UI code in the view because it's against the architecture, and makes maintenance more difficult.// There's nothing wrong going against the architecture (if it doesnt help), after all architecture is to help us, not for us to stick to it. What I was saying was if you dont get any benefit out of separating view and presenter, then why write them in two namespaces? Ok now you say there's a maintenance benefit. Not sure about that. There's more brain wracking required when you separate view and ui logic. That's subjective I leave it.

Comment: But the benefit of separating view and presenter into two projects is that you can easily change the view later without having to modify the presenter. 

// If you significantly change your presenter, all the views still have to be updated, so having them all in separate projects gains you nothing in terms of maintainability,// That's where you got me wrong. MVP (or any design pattern for that matter) is not to help change of presenter! presenter anyway will have only ui logic. Its to change View easily without having to impact presenter!

Comment: While all this time by different views I did not mean `cutomerview`, `employeeview` etc. All those views should come under one project, and all their corresponding presenters should come under another. By different views I meant different ui applications - a web application, a desktop application, a mobile app etc all which use the same business model. In such a case you need just one presenter project. That's a huge advantage. Ok I might make my own answer, the only reason i refrain is because this question is about asp.net which I have never worked with..

Answer (score 0):

Below would be a nice start. You could split up even more if the project gets bigger:

```
Company.Project.Core -> Controller logic
Company.Project.Domain -> Domain models (view models and database models)
Company.Project.Interface -> Views, presenters
```

Comment: `Core` is normally reserved for domain classes, which by the way should *not* be in the same assembly/namespace as data models (assuming that your project actually has both). `UI` is also a more typical convention for user-interface code than `Interface`.